# Run BeautifulSoup web scrape continuously and show the newest change in headline

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using python in pycharm.
I am following news on the NY Times politics website. Right now my code allows me to see the latest article in NY Times politics. I would want the code to run continuously and only want to print out the latest headline when there is a new article. How would I go about in doing that?

Here is my code so far:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nytimes.com/section/politics"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
article = soup.find('h2', class_='css-1j9dxys e1xfvim30').text
print(article)
```

Comment: Saving the latest content's URL and keep looking continuously, then retrieve if the last one's URL doesn't match the one you have saved. Does this fit for you? I'm saying URL because they are unique for every content.

Comment: How would I go about saving the content URL? I need it to be running every second and see the newest article headline printed in real time.

Comment: For a basic work you can save it to a txt file. If you will do this work for multiple sites in the future, you can create a json file that keeps site url (`https://www.nytimes.com/section/politics`) as keys and latest url (`https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/31/us/politics/house-impeachment-vote.html`) as values. Then loop all items in that json and keep track of newest headlines from different sites.

Comment: And of course, you need to get the new's URL using `BeautifulSoup`. If you don't want to do that, you can just keep the content itself instead of URL, but it's not that practical.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

article = ""
time_between_refresh = 900  #15 minutes

while True:
    url = "https://www.nytimes.com/section/politics"
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    new_article = soup.find('h2', class_='css-1j9dxys e1xfvim30').text

    if article != new_article:
        print(article)
        article = new_article

    time.sleep(time_between_refresh)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. Im getting this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Trader/PycharmProjects/trial/nytimes.py", line 20, in <module>
    time.wait(time_between_refresh)
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'wait'

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated my code from time.wait() to time.sleep()